# Por que isso não funciona em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, orientação-a-objetos

Por que não consigo declarar uma variável "endereco" no inicio da definição da classe? E como o `JavaScript` consegue declarar as variáveis de classe utilizando somente `this.nome_variavel`?

```
class Pessoa {
    var endereco;
    constructor(nome, cpf){
        this.nome = nome;
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }
    printPessoa(){
        console.log('Nome: '+ this.nome);
        console.log('CPF: '+this.cpf);
        console.log('Endereco: '+this.endereco);
    }
    setEndereco(endereco){
        this.endereco = endereco;
    }
}
```

Comment: Qual será o valor de `endereco` se eu instanciar `Pessoa` e não chamar o método `setEndereco`?

Comment: acredito que undefined pois toda variável não inicializada em JS tem esse valor como default

Answer (score 1):

Pense na classe, como uma estrutura similar a um JSON, o JSON é uma estrutura simples, similar ao XML, é bom salientar que a classe é um modelo/template, e o objeto JSON é um modelo personalizado com valores ou estado:

Sua classe:

```
class Pessoa {

}
```

Quando você constrói um JSON, escreverá algo similar a isso:

```
var pessoa = {propriedade: "valor"}
```

Quando atribui um método para uma propriedade da sua classe, fará algo similar a isso:

```
class Pessoa { 

    propriedade: function() {

    } 

}
```

Veja o exemplo abaixo, imagine que você tenha tentado fazer o mesmo com uma estrutura JSON.

Por acaso já viu alguém fazer declarações dentro de um JSON como isso? Conseguiu identificar o problema abaixo?

```
//ISSO É IMPOSSÍVEL!!!
var pessoa = {

 var endereco;

}
```

Então... Sem declarar com "var" funcionará, porque ele passa a ser uma propriedade, que é parte do escopo das chaves da sua classe. E como neste caso você não atribuiu valores ou métodos para esta propriedade, ela se torna uma propriedade indefinida:

`pessoa.endereco //retornará undefined`

[Vale uma leitura aqui para entender melhor](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)

Answer (score 0):

A classe no javascript não trabalha com escopo utilizando var, se você retirar o var do inicio da sua propriedade endereço funcionará. Mas será atributo o valor undefined de início.

Dentro do javascript ele entende classe como um objeto. Por exemplo

```js
class ClasseObjeto {
 propriedadeA // undefined

 constructor(){
  this.propriedadeB = true;
 }

 getA() {
  return this.propriedadeA
 }
 setA( valor ) {
  this.propriedadeA = valor
 }

}

var Objeto = {
 propriedadeA: undefined,
 propriedadeB: true,
 setA: function( valor ){ this.propriedadeA = valor }
 getA: function(){ return this.propriedadeA }
}
```